# what is the exception being thrown in this code:

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Testex
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
       double [] scores = new double [5];
       scores [5] = 95.75;

    }
}
```

im not sure what exception is being thrown here, any help please

Comment: Please edit your question to be readable

Comment: If you're not sure what exception is being thrown, look at the stack trace you get and you'll see.

Answer (score 7):

double[5] is not the last element in the array, double[4] is (arrays are zero-based in java)

Answer (score 5):

That would be an Index Out Of Range Exception (arrays are 0 based, not 1 based):

```
 scores[5] = 95.75; // references the sixth element of a five element array
```

Comment: Thanks for not posting the literal class name. It may be the point of the homework to find out whether the student has actually managed to run the program.

Answer (score 2):

if the array is of size five, the allowed indexes are 0-4.

So you are probably getting an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

The Exception would be an IndexOutOfBoundsException because arrays are are 0-based. So the first index is [0].  When you reference [5] this is the 6th slot but the array only has 5 slots.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to initialize score outside of bound? Java arrays start at 0. This looks like homework...